# EF Core: Is it possible to have a dynamic defaultValue? E.g. depending on another value?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

For example I have two simple string properties inside my model:

```cs
public class Model
{
    public string BaseString {get;set;}
    public string MyValue {get;set;}
}
```

Inside my OnModelCreating:

```cs
modelBuilder
.Entity<Model>()
.Property(f => f.MyValue)
.ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
.HasDefaultValueSQL(//insert first letter of inserted BaseString property + something else);
```

Is something like that possible? Or can default values only be constants?
What is the correct approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible. The following was the configuration tested;

```
modelBuilder
.Entity<Model>()
.Property(f => f.MyValue)
.HasDefaultValueSQL("CONCAT(SUBSTRING(BaseString, 0, 1), \'something else\')");
```

And the following migration generated;

```
  migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Test",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
                    BaseString = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    MyValue = table.Column<string>(nullable: true, defaultValueSql: "CONCAT(SUBSTRING(BaseString, 0, 1), 'something else')")
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Test", x => x.Id);
                });
```

Yet, when tried to apply the migration, the following error generated. And the error is quite descriptive about the supporting configurations.

> The name "BaseString" is not permitted in this context. Valid
>   expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some
>   contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted.

Comment: okay so I will have to do it all in C# beforehand and then just insert the finished property... 

Then comes a new question: How to incorporate a sequence stored on the db into c#.

I guess I will have to do some research and then ask a new question.

Comment: You can write a setter to [BaseString] property and set the value for [MyValue] there.